# Include the current product category name at the top of the single product page in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

Just wanted to ask if anyone here can tell me how to include the current product category name at the top of the single product page in Woocommerce.

I'm going to want to place it above the breadcrumb trail at the top of my product page. I've included a link to an example of what I'm looking for here: http://www.espguitars.com/guitars/signature/kirk.html -

Notice at the top right-hand corner of the page you'll see the current category name, in this case, the category name is Guitars. I realize that the site example I've given is not a wordpress site, but I feel certain there's a way to do this with woocommerce.

Comment: This must be what you were looking for
https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/3206230 I pasted it in `functions.php`, edited line 33 like in the comments and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the meta.php file in the "templates/single-product" folder of the WooCommerce plugin, you'll see how the WooCommerce plugin displays the product categories of the current product as product meta information.

```
<?php
...
global $post, $product;
?>
<div class="product_meta">
...
<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>
...
</div>
```

Please copy the code to your theme and modify it accordingly.